# How to enter multiple values in local storage by dictionary using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

In my code I will update a value but I will not store a new value. Suppose I have to enter some value in the following format:

```
{
   firstname:'kuldeep', 
   lastname:- 'patel'
}
```

Then after value is entered, the value is updated. This value is stored in localStorage. However I want to add some different value like the following:

```
{
   firstname: 'kuldeep',
   lastname: 'patel', 
   firstname:'abc', 
   lastname:'xyz',    
   firstname:'parth', 
   lastname:'pandy'
}
```

Here is my code for taking the above input:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.save').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {
            "Firstname": $('#name').val(),
            "Lastname": $('#lastname').val()
        };

        var saveData = JSON.stringify(data);

        if( typeof(Storage) !== undefined ){
            localStorage.setItem("savedItem", saveData );
            document.write(savedItem);
        } else {
            alert('Storage is not available in your browser!');
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Create an array `[{firstname: 'kuldeep', lastname: 'patel'},{firstname:'parth',lastname:'pandy'}]` => stringify => `localStorage.setItem`

Comment: in this code user enter so how can i do ?

Comment: i think list  dictionary use

Comment: You can use array like my answer @KuldeepPatel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array like this :

```
$('.save').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!localStorage)
        return alert('Storage is not available in your browser!');

    const savedItem = ((savedItem) => {
        try {
            return (savedItem) ? JSON.parse(savedItem) : [];
        } catch (e) { return []; }
        if (!a instanceof Array)
             return [];
    })(localStorage.savedItem);

    const data = {
        "Firstname": $('#name').val(),
        "Lastname": $('#lastname').val()
    };

    savedItem.push(data);

    localStorage.savedItem = JSON.stringify(savedItem);

    console.log(localStorage.savedItem);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" />
<input id="lastname" />


<input class="save" type="button" value="save" />
```

output (object):

```
[{
   firstname: 'kuldeep',
   lastname: 'patel',
}, { 
   firstname:'abc', 
   lastname:'xyz',
}, {
   firstname:'parth', 
   lastname:'pandy'
}]
```

Comment: savedItem.push(data); //Uncaught TypeError: savedItem.push is not a function

Comment: Before try : `localStorage.savedItem` use `localStorage.savedItem = ""`

Comment: But I edited my code, it prevents this issue (bad JSON object) .